# How to stop displaying control characters like ^M and ^H in neovim on macOS?

Tags: neovim

I exported in .zshrc:

```bash
export MANPAGER="nvim"
```

Now when I do:

```bash
man tree
```

It shows control characters, like so
[image]

How do I turn this off showing these characters in neovim and instead show just the text?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in `:help manpager.vim`, which recommends

```
export MANPAGER="vim +MANPAGER --not-a-term -"
```

or equivalent for your shell. (The scripts involved post-process formatted manpages to look correct in Vim, including removing control characters.)